# How feasible would it be to use power bi to create a full screen dashboard with 60 second refresh frequency

Tags: powerbi, fullscreen, powerbi-desktop, dashboard

I have created a framework (written in delphi) for creating live full-screen dashboards. These dashboards are based on the result of a single albeit long SQL query ~1000 lines. The dashboard is refreshed every  60 seconds using the results from the query. Each cell is formatted based on metadata returned as part of the query result. Some of the cells are populated with icons again based on the query result. Further some of the cells will display extra information when clicked on and for some cells this information is password protected.
Our organisation finds these dashboard extremely useful but would prefer if they could be creating in powerbi. I am not a powerbi expert and would value an expert opinion on the feasibility of this approach.[image: example dashboard]

In particular the feasibility of:

1. Displaying full-screen without the various powerbi menus/icons etc.
2. Password controlled extra info.
3. Filling cells with variable number of icons.
4. 60 Second refresh rates assuming query runtimes of <3 seconds.

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 3):

1. In Power BI service, File > Embed Report > Website or Portal. You will get a URL. Copy the URL and at the end add “&navContentPaneEnabled=false”. This will hide the page navigation bar. Open this embed URL in a new tab. This is secure because you cannot see content without logging in. To have the page show full screen without white spaces, set the page view settings to ‘Fit to page’ or change the page size to match the display or TV and then set page view to ‘Actual Size’. (Credit to Greedy_Simple9090 on reddit. I have tested and it works exactly as described)
2. You can't password control info but you can have Row Level Security. This would be applied for the currently logged in user though. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls
3. This is trivial and would be driven by DAX measures.
4. Power BI has different licences. Pro is restricted to 8 times a day and Premium is 48 times a day. To achieve your objectives, you could look at either real time streaming (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming) or Direct Query mode with a browser timed refresh. There is also the refresh APIs (probably not worth using Import mode for such a refresh frequency though) or 3rd party services like this: https://www.displagent.io/

Comment: I'm the founder of Displagent, thanks for the shoutout @Davide Bacci! Happy to provide further info for anyone!